# Растянуть div на весь экран и отступить от краёв

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! Вообщем, есть Div небольшой. Нужно растянуть его на весь экран и отступить от краёв. Я присваиваю

`width: calc(100% - 40px);
padding: 0 20px;`

Отображается всё отлично, у большинства. Но.. Не у всех. Многие используют браузеры постарее и не слезают. Скажем оперу 12. Из-за чего мне пишут вечно, что панель выглядит не так как надо.

Как бы растянуть панель на весь экран и отступить от краёв по 20px, для нормального отображения?

Пробовал ещё так:

```
width: 100%;
padding: 0 20px;
```

Но, панель приобретает экран полного вида. Отступая от левого края на 20. А правым лезет за экран.

Answer (score 2):

а сделайте ещё box-sizing: border-box

то есть, в общем так:

```
width: 100%;
padding: 0 20px;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

и будет счастье

Answer (score 1):

Мб так?

```
width: 100%;  
margin: 0 20px; - внешний отступ, от объекта  
padding: 0 20px;
```